# "Please upgrade python" when I have 3.7 and "Please upgrade pip" when I have 20.0.2. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

I wanted to download the [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) library to crop images on Python, but I just can't download the module. Here's what appears in the terminal:

```
pip install PIL
```

Output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Then I tried this out. But another error showed up:

```
python3 -m pip install PIL
```

Output:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I tried to upgrade my pip. But then this showed up:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.0.2-py2.7.egg (20.0.2)
```

When I check my pip version it shows this:

```
pip --version
```

Output:

```
pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
```

When I check my Python version it shows this

```
python --version
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.10
```

```
python3 --version
```

Output:

```
Python 3.7.1
```

So I downloaded pip3 and then tried the command

```
pip3 install PIL
```

Output:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

I also tried what they said.

```
python3 -m pip3 install PIL
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3: No module named pip3
```

Here are some details about my pip and the Python interpreter:

```
which pip3
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
```

```
which python3
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

How do I solve this once and for all?

Comment: you have to install `Pillow`, not `PIL` . Doc: [Pillow (PIL Fork)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Comment: And if you use `-m` it's always `pip` and never `pip3`.

Comment: BTW: you have two messages. First is only warning that you have old version of `pip` - but it is only warning, not error and it has nothing to do with second message and you can ignore for this moment. Second is error because this module has name `pillow`

Comment: Ok Thanks! downloading Pillow worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Python 2 is no longer supported, Pip 2 (invoked by either `pip` or `python -m pip`) is complaining that you should use Python 3. The package manager for Python 3 is called pip3 (invoked by `pip3` or `python3 -m pip`).

Your pip3 is currently the latest version and you don’t need to take any action to upgrade pip3.

If you want to use PIL in Python then I recommend you to [install Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html). [Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) is the PIL of Python 3.
You should be able to install Pillow with `pip3 install Pillow`. Pillow supersedes PIL. (unless you specifically want to use PIL with Python 2)

Perhaps you want to configure your terminal to alias pip to pip3, so you won’t call pip2 by mistake.